# Cant Turn Tuple Into String

Tags: python, flask

I am struggling to display two columns (resultlist) in seperate columns. Right now when i return result list its showing in a tuple. When i try to index the for loop(to remove the tuple) with i[0] in the HTML file but i get the first character which is the "("

current output:

```
column1
('123456', '150.92') 
('49815', '70.43') 
('19971', '39.35')
```

If i try to index the for loop in html, current output:

```
column1 
 (
 (
 (
```

expected output:

```
Column1      Column2
123456       150.92
49815        70.43
19971        39.35
```

Current python file:

```
def subtractboth(alloclist, statementlist):
    resultlist = []

    for i, j in zip(statementlist, alloclist):
        if i[0] == j[0]:
            results = float(j[1]) - float(i[1])
            if results >= 0:
                results = i[0], "{:.2f}".format(results)
                print(" ".join(results))
                resultlist.append(str(results))
    return resultlist


@app.route('/results', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main():
    connect()
    masteracct = request.args.get('masteracct')
    cashdt = request.args.get('cashdt')
    billdt = request.args.get('billdt')
    allocation(connect(), cashdt, masteracct)
    statement(connect(), billdt, masteracct)
    a = subtractboth(statement(connect(), billdt, masteracct), allocation(connect(), cashdt,
                                                                          masteracct))
    html = render_template('test_results.html', a=a)
    return html
```

HTML:

```
<table>
 <th>Column 1</th>
 <th> Column 2</th>
 {% for i in a %}
 <tr>
    <td>{{i}}</td>
    <td>{{i}}</td>
 </tr>
 {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: You shouldn't convert the tuples to strings before appending them to the list. This makes it very hard to separate the elements again: `resultlist.append(str(results))` Just append the `results` directly and then you can use @VPfB's answer below.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Thank you!! this did the trick along with VPBS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jinja2 template for displaying a table with 2 columns should look like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>column1</th>
        <th>column2</th>
    </tr>
    {% for v1, v2 in a %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ v1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ v2 }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

The variable `a` should be a sequence of pairs.

Comment: When i try that i get ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: @iampython2134 I cannot run your Python code, but could you modify it to pass a list/tuple of table rows, where each item is a list/tuple of columns? Something like ``a=[(a1, a1), (b1, b2), (c1, c2), ...]``